# read json file from FTP

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, ftp

I am working with some codes to be able to get data from json file and upload data to html table. Works perfectly with this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var myArray = []


    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'https://reqres.in/api/users',
        success:function(response){
            myArray = response.data
            buildTable(myArray)
            console.log(myArray)
        }
    })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].first_name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].last_name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].email}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }

</script>
```

json file is somewhere, provide url to the folder, use ajax to get it, build table in html and display data.

is there possibility to get file from FTP server? or do you know where can I send data automatically and get url from that site (and use this code)? ajax doesnt respond well to ftp and I can not send automatically file to github (or any other site I know. uploading files manually is not the point). Can you point me to the right direction please?

ideal would be to read json file from the same folder where index.html is so I tried this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("test.json", function(data){
            console.log(data.name); // Prints: Harry
            console.log(data.age); // Prints: 14
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

but nothing happened

Comment: guess I am doing something wrong, cause I can not find anything about that. Can you point me in the right direction if you know what to look

Comment: Thanks for the link. The answer is: It would be magic to have full ftp in JS. It's a big task though. ipv4, ipv6, sftp, line endings, encoding, multiple protocol versions, file permissions. It's a complex protocol and I don't think it's possible unless there is a financial incentive – 
Eddie
 Oct 19, 2019 at 1:54
So, as I said, can not be done. Is there any other solution? Is there a site where can I send my data automatically and just put url in code?

Comment: The question seems to be unclear. The title is _"read JSON from FTP"_. Ajax already supports IPv4 and IPv6. SFTP is a different protocol. Ajax supports line endings. _"s there a site where can I send my data automatically and just put url in code?"_ This question is off-topic. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for programming questions, not for service recommendations.